# How i can know the consumption (cost) an App Service has consumed sp far RRS feed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service inside our azure portal, where this app service host a SharePoint remote event receiver as follow:-

[image]

the app service has been live for around 2 months, but i am not sure how i can know the cost/consumption this app service has consumed so far?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers here, depending on how accurate of a price you need.  The easy/obvious answer if you just need to know how much this app service is costing per month/hour is to look that up in the pricing table on the MS web site.  Go to the pricing page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/), select your OS and region, and scroll down to the S1 Standard Service Plan to see its cost per month (or hour).

If you need to your your own, exact billed amount for a specific time period, then you need to use the "Cost Management + Billing" section of the Azure Portal (assuming you have rights within your org to view Cost info).

Click on "Cost Management & Billing" if it's on your sidebar, otherwise click "All Services" and search for it.  Then click "Cost Management" and then "Cost Analysis" in the sidebar.  At the top, select "Cost by Resource" and select the time period you wish to know the cost for (you can select specific dates, or "This month" or "Last 7 days", etc).  A list of your resources will appear on the page with their costs for that time period.  Simply scroll down to the name of your App Service Plan (ending in "-a256") and that is your cost for that period.

Note that multiple App Services can share a single App Service Plan and you pay for the Plan, not the individual apps in it.  So the cost you see is for the Plan, regardless of the number of apps running in it.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. but when i click on "Cost by Resource" i did not get any of the app services resources, i only get 1 resource for MFA.. now one thing to mention when i create the app service which hosts the remote event receiver i chose the subscription as "Microsft Azure" and not Pay-as-You-Go.. so does this explain why i can not find the app service inside the cost management?

Comment: I only have a single Azure subscription, so I may not be able to help.  But if you click on the "Scope" option you should be able to change to whatever Subscription you want.

Comment: Seems cost analysis is not available yet for Microsoft Azure, as inside the Scope it says coming soon..